# How to use homogeneous coordinates and the projective plane to study the intersection of two lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, mathematical-modeling, plane-curves, homogeneous-spaces

How to use homogeneous coordinates and the projective plane to study the intersection of two lines, and how to compare this to a standard homogeneous coordinates.
*The equation of a line in inhomogeneous coordinates is
a · x + b · y + c = 0, for some a, b, c ∈ R

What do we get for the intersection in
* homogeneous coordinates,
* inhomogeneous coordinates
if the lines are parallel, and non parallel.
What do we get for the equation of the line passing through two points p1, p2 (in homogeneous coordinates)?

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: When you express 2-d geometry problem in homogeneous coordinates, the point lying on the intersection of two lines is given by a cross product, the line passing through two points is also given by a cross product. The existence of a familiar algebraic object  allow some point/line intersection problem much easier to handle through algebra.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the equation of a line through two points in the projective plane with determinant:
$$\begin{vmatrix}x_1&x_2&X\\
y_1&y_2&Y\\t_1&t_2&T\end{vmatrix}=0.$$